# Aligning grid based form elements and their labels

Tags: css

we have a requirement where form elements are laid out in 3 separate columns. The labels can have varying amounts of text and the form elements will be mainly input boxes and textarea's.

The designers want to ensure that the input elements are vertically aligned correctly.We are unable to use specific padding/margins as this is not flexible when the app is localized.

Please see the image below. The first row shows the issue we are experiencing and the second is how we would like it laid out. The only solution we have thought of is placing the label in a separate row to the actual form element. I cant imagine this would be good for accessibility.

Any tips really appreciated.

[image]

Here is a fiddle of the code so far - http://jsfiddle.net/nJZ6Y/4/

`<div class="grid_4">
            <div class="contents">
              <label>TR 1 TD 1</label>
              <input type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4">
            <div class="contents">
                <label>Bonorum Fermentum Tortor Adipiscing Pharetra</label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nJZ6Y/19/

You have to add a `span` inside each `label`, then add these CSS rules.

```
label {
    min-height: 3em;
}

label span {
    vertical-align: -3em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Fred, this is awesome. What about if the label text spilled over onto 4 lines in some cases ? Would the min-height value need to be adapted for this ?

Comment: @grimmus Yes, definitely. You are going to have to experiment. If you know the maximum number of lines for the label, that will be of use. Also, please check for browser compatibility because I was working with IE10.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nJZ6Y/18/

I added a box around the label element and aligned it to the bottom. This only works if you know the approximate max-height of the text though. If the text goes longer than that it will fall out of the container and go incognito. Fred's answer is more elegant. 
FYI: Bonorum in your lorem ipsum is a funny word...

```
    .label-box {
        position: relative;
    }
    .label-box {
        height: 50px;
    }
    label { 
        float:left; 
        width:100%; 
        color:#fff; 
        position: absolute; 
        bottom: 0; 
        left: 0;}
```